# Ререндер компонента при изменении данных вне хука | React

Tags: reactjs

Есть класс Contacts.

```
class Contacts {
    list: [1,2,3,4]
    
    ...

    useList() {
        return this.list;
    }

    update() {
    //Вот тут...
    }
}
```

Мне надо, чтобы компонент, внутри которого будет использоваться Contacts.useList(), ререндерился так, словно используется хук.

```
...
const contactsList = Contacts.useList();
...
useEffect(() => { ... }, [contactsList]);
...
```

Как такое возможно сделать? Я знаю, что можно написать новый хук, но тогда мне придется подписываться на изменения данных в dom или т.п. Кто-то сталкивался с такой задачей?

Comment: Как `Contacts.useList` планируется вызывать из компонента?

Comment: Как и написано в коде, прямо внутри функционального компонента.

Comment: Т.к. реакт будет рендерить компонент только при изменении состояния, то результаты придется положить в переменную состояния и вызывать метод класса по какому то событию. Вообще это не самый правильный подход. Может вам стоит посмотреть на библиотеку Redux?

Comment: Она используется. Но этот хук должен существовать и вне стора. Сейчас я использую комбинацию кастомного хука и событий документ для динамического обновления, но хотелось бы использовать так, как описано в примере. Поэтому и задал тут вопрос, есть ли какая-то функция/метод ререндера реакта